# discrete math help in proving power set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

if this happens:

[image: if this happens]

show that [image] or [image]

what I tried:

$P(A  ∪B)=P(A)∪P(B)$

$ x∈ P(A  ∪B ) ==> x⊆(A∪B) ===>x⊆A  \ or \ x⊆B $

$ if \  x⊆A==>x∈P(A)==>x∈P(A)∪P(B) $

$ if \ x⊆B ==>x∈P(B)==>x∈P(A)∪P(B) $

would like to know if its the route

Comment: $x\subseteq (A\cup B)$ does not imply that $x\subseteq A$ or $x\subseteq B$.  Take for counterexample $\{2,3\}\subseteq (\{1,2\}\cup \{3,4\})$ despite $\{2,3\}$ neither being a subset of $\{1,2\}$ nor being a subset of $\{3,4\}$.  You have confused this with $x\in (A\cup B)$

Comment: so all i did was wrong? how can i work with the power set to prove what iv`e been asked? can`t think of any transitions but $ x∈P(A) ==> x⊆A $

Comment: You can show that $x\subseteq A$ or $x\subseteq B$ here by a different route though... here by noting that $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)=\mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B)$ and so $x\in \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)\implies x\in \mathcal{P}(A)\cup\mathcal{P}(B)\implies x\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ or $x\in\mathcal{P}(B)$.  I don't know that it is relevant however as talking about a random $x\in \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$ doesn't help us investigate the relationship between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: For a corrected approach, try contrapositive or contradiction.  Suppose that it was not the case that $A\subseteq B$ and it was also not the case that $B\subseteq A$.  That means what?  That there is some $a\in A\setminus B$ as well as some $b\in B\setminus A$.  What can you say about the set $\{a,b\}$ then?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A \nsubseteq B$ and $B \nsubseteq A$. Then there exists an $a \in A \smallsetminus B$ and a $b \in B \smallsetminus A$. But then $\{ a, b \} \in \mathcal{P} ( A \cup B ) $ but $\{ a, b \} \notin \mathcal{P}( A ) \cup \mathcal{P}( B ) $. Thus $\mathcal{P} ( A \cup B ) \neq \mathcal{P}( A ) \cup \mathcal{P}( B ) $. Using contraposition; if $\mathcal{P} ( A \cup B ) = \mathcal{P}( A ) \cup \mathcal{P}( B ) $, then it is not the case that $A \nsubseteq B$ and $B \nsubseteq A$. That is to say, $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$. Since $b \notin A$, $\{ a, b \} \notin \mathcal{P} ( A ) $. Similarly, since $a \notin B$, $\{ a, b \} \notin \mathcal{P} ( B ) $.

Comment: thank you,but why {a,b}∈P(A∪B) but not {a,b}∉P(A)∪P(B)

Comment: @anton5450 because $\{a,b\}$ is indeed an element of $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$ since both $a$ is an element of $A\cup B$ as well as $b$ is an element of $A\cup B$.  On the other hand, $\{a,b\}$ can not be an element of $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B)$ since if it were then that would have implied that either $\{a,b\}$ were an element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ which it isn't since $b\notin A$ or that $\{a,b\}$ were an element of $\mathcal{P}(B)$ which it isn't since $a\notin B$.

Comment: @anton5450 We had very specifically picked these elements $a,b$ for the very useful fact that $a\in A\setminus B$ which means that $a\in A$ while $a\notin B$ and that similarly $b\in B\setminus A$ which means that $b\in B$ while $b\notin A$ and that we knew that $\{a,b\}$ would cause trouble.